# (1/1) SmartyException Source: Missing name in smarty_template_source.php line 169, with TM Mega Menu Module in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: caching, menu, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm encountering a problem with my Prestashop 1.7 website, specifically when the TM Mega Menu module v1.7.2 (by Alexander Grosul from TemplateMonster) is enabled. The error I receive is:

```
`(1/1) SmartyException
Source: Missing name

in smarty_template_source.php line 169
at Smarty_Template_Source::load()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 168
at Smarty_Internal_Template->__construct()
in Smarty.class.php line 1028
at Smarty->createTemplate()
in Module.php line 2518
at ModuleCore->getCurrentSubTemplate()
in Module.php line 2569
at ModuleCore->isCached()
in tmmegamenu.php line 2764
at Tmmegamenu->renderWidget()
in Hook.php line 1018
at HookCore::coreRenderWidget()
in Hook.php line 43
etc.
```

This issue disappears when I disable the TM Mega Menu module. I've created my own child theme for Prestashop 1.7. I've noticed that when the TM Mega Menu module is active, no files are being created in the Smarty cache directory. However, when the module is disabled, cache files start to appear.

The problem started after I migrated the shop to a different server, which runs a different PHP version. The old server was using PHP 7.3, and the new one is on PHP 7.4. Unfortunately, I don't have the option to upgrade the module or change the PHP version. My Prestashop version 1.7.8.6

Any advice or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried clearing the cache multiple times and experimented with various settings for Smarty cache generation, but the problem persists.